# Problems Sending Signals to the Arduino-Uno via Keyboard

Tags: arduino-uno, led, usb, shields, keyboard

I have an Arduino Uno and a usb 2.0 shield in which I connected a keyboard to. I have all the necessary libraries installed but what I am trying to figure out is how to light an led when I press a specific key.

I am new to codding Arduino boards and I have done a lot of reading but I cant figure out my issue I feel like if I get this figured out I will be a lot better off in my future projects.

```
#include <hidboot.h>
#include <usbhub.h>
#ifdef dobogusinclude
#include <spi4teensy3.h>
#endif
#include <SPI.h>

int SKEY = 8;

class KbdRptParser : public KeyboardReportParser
{
    void PrintKey(uint8_t mod, uint8_t key);

  protected:

    void OnKeyDown  (uint8_t mod, uint8_t key);
    void OnKeyUp    (uint8_t mod, uint8_t key);
    void OnKeyPressed            (uint8_t key);
};

void KbdRptParser::PrintKey(uint8_t m, uint8_t key)
{
  MODIFIERKEYS mod;
  *((uint8_t*)&mod) = m;
  Serial.print((mod.bmLeftCtrl   == 1) ? "C" : " ");
  Serial.print((mod.bmLeftShift  == 1) ? "S" : " ");
  Serial.print((mod.bmLeftAlt    == 1) ? "A" : " ");
  Serial.print((mod.bmLeftGUI    == 1) ? "G" : " ");

  Serial.print(" >");
  PrintHex<uint8_t>(key, 0x80);
  Serial.print("< ");

  Serial.print((mod.bmRightCtrl   == 1) ? "C" : " ");
  Serial.print((mod.bmRightShift  == 1) ? "S" : " ");
  Serial.print((mod.bmRightAlt    == 1) ? "A" : " ");
  Serial.println((mod.bmRightGUI  == 1) ? "G" : " ");
};

void KbdRptParser::OnKeyDown(uint8_t mod, uint8_t key)
{
  Serial.print("DN ");
  PrintKey(mod, key);
  uint8_t c = OemToAscii(mod, key);

}

void KbdRptParser::OnKeyUp(uint8_t mod, uint8_t key)
{
  Serial.print("UP ");
  PrintKey(mod, key);
}

void KbdRptParser::OnKeyPressed(uint8_t key)
{
  Serial.print("ASCII: ");
  Serial.println((char)key);
};

USB Usb;
HIDBoot<USB_HID_PROTOCOL_KEYBOARD>    HidKeyboard(&Usb);

KbdRptParser Prs;

void setup() { 
 
 Serial.begin(9600);
#if !defined(__MIPSEL__)
  while (!Serial); 
  Serial.println("Start");

  if (Usb.Init() == -1)
    Serial.println("OSC did not start.");

  delay( 1 );

  HidKeyboard.SetReportParser(0, &Prs);

}

void loop() {
 Usb.Task();
}
```

Anyways I know how to make if statements and how to activate pins on the Arduino but I cant figure it out in this keyboard library. For now I just made it print "TRUE" since there is not need to get complicated if I cant get the first step to work. Before I made that if statement the serial monitor would show the value assigned to the key and label it DN # and when I let up on the key it would say UP # but how can I translate that to sending a pulse to whatever pin when I push a key and stop sending a pulse when I let up on the key?

Also in my if statement that I made I know I need something before == sign but I tried multiple things and they did not work so I just left it blank and the reason I used the number 16 was because that was the value assigned to the S key in which I wanted to use to light an led. Anyways any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what LED are you talking about? ... you have no LED control code in your sketch

Comment: you can print `DN` when a key is pressed ...  why can't you turn on an LED when a key is pressed?

Comment: `sending a pulse to whatever pin when I push a key and stop sending a pulse` ... that only applies to a flashing LED ... if you turn on a LED and leave it on, then that is not a pulse

Comment: I dont want to leave an led on... I want to be able to push a key to turn on an led and when I let up on that key the led should turn off. Also I made it clear that I have not made the led code yet because if I cant figure out how to make the proper if-statement none of it will work. Every time I try I get an error which was the whole reason I asked this question I know the code to make an led light up but I dont know how to do that while using the keyboard library...

Comment: your post says nothing about an error ... why don't you turn on the LED right after you print `DN`? ... turn off the LED right after you print `UP`

Comment: If I could I would... why else would I be asking this question if I knew how to do it...

Comment: i do not understand ... find the line that prints `DN` ... insert a line that turns on the LED right after it

Comment: The only `if` statement I see is `if (Usb.Init() == -1)` but that doesn't seem like one you are having trouble with. What is the full exact error message you get from the Arduino IDE when you compile your code?

Comment: Did you post the wrong code?  Where is this if statement you are talking about?

Comment: In the oneKeyDown routine you get a parameter called key that has the key that was pressed.  Save it to a variable and you can put that variable in an if statement to do whatever you want if it is equal to some value.  Or just light the led when the button is pressed right there in that routine.

Answer (score 1):

Keyboards cannot be used quite like you wish - the keyboard will send a key (scan) code when a key is pressed and then repeat that code if the button continues to be pressed. There is a different code sent when the same key is released.

> The scancode for key release is obtained from it by setting the high
> order bit (adding 0x80 = 128). Thus, Esc press produces scancode 01,
> Esc release scancode 81 (hex).  For sequences things are similar:
> Keypad-/ gives e0 35 when pressed, e0 b5 when released. Most keyboards
> will repeat the make code (key down code) when the key repeats.

From: [https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-1.html](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-1.html)

Comment: Very strange because when I press a key there is a specific number or number letter combo attached to it. For example when I look at the serial monitor it knows what key I am pressing and for how long. I dont understand how the Arduino knows via the serial monitor what key is being pressed and is able to print it but wont cant send a pulse to a specific pin based on the duration the key is held down. If the Arduino is aware of the specific key being pressed and its duration there is no reason it cant light an led up.

Comment: @CyClone Well, this question and its answer were left alone, because you did not edit your question answering 1) how you tried to control the LED, and 2) which error you got trying.